# What would be an appropriate constrained optimization solver in python for this problem; and type error problem

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am looking to use python (in place of excel) for an assignment in a non-programming related engineering class.  I am trying to find the optimum number of tubes in a heat exchanger for several differently sized tubes.  This number depends on half a dozen related quantities and has a few constraints.  Few of these equations are linear, but the number of tubes has to be a positive integer.  I know about the scipy.optimize package and using math.ceil to turn the trial numbers into integers, but there has to be a nicer package out their somewhere.

I put the code as it stands [here](https://github.com/wdkrnls/Design-Homework-2/blob/master/hw2.py).

Below is the section with the optimization problem.  The trouble is that fsolve doesn't change enough to change the initial guess with the m.ceil in there.

```
def ntf():
    fdn = 0.85 * 62.43 
    #            lb/ft^3
    vsb = fdn * 5 * (1.076 * 10 ** -5)
    #     lb/ft^3 * Cst * (ft^2/s) / Cst
    kf  = 0.08
    fcp  = 0.5
    #     Btu/ft^2-hr-(F/ft)
    dua = uaf()

    for i, x in enumerate(bwg16):
        def func(nt):
            nt   = m.ceil(nt)
            vel  = velf(nt, x)
            nre  = nref(vel, bwg16[x][1], fdn, vsb)
            npr  = nprf(fcp, vsb, kf)
            nnu  = nnuf(nre, npr, vsb, vsb)
            idc  = idcf(nnu, bwg16[x][1], kf)
            ohtc = ohtcf(idc, x)
            fa   = nt * bwg16[x][3]
            sa   = 40 * nt * bwg16[x][2] 
            ua   = ohtc * sa
            diff = ua - dua
            return diff

        nts[x] = opt.fsolve(func, 40, xtol = 0.01)
        # TODO:  Optimize nt such that diff is positive but as close to zero as
        # possible.  nt needs to be an integer.  Then, I need to be able to
        # extract nt, nre, vel, and sa into a dictionary to compare later.  If
        # all else fails, I suppose I could recalculate the rest later given
        # the working nt.

    return nts
```

In summary, can you recommend a better package or function in python that could handle this problem?

*Edit: I got rid of an type error problem I was having due to forgetting some return statements.*

Comment: You should print the exact stack trace you're getting, so we can see the line that is failing. Also, calculating each piece of an equation on a separate line will help to track down exactly which calculation is failing. The error tells us that you're trying to do a ** comparison against None, which means one of your variables hasn't been set correctly, or the math is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let the optimizer work with float values, perhaps you can assume that correct integer result is either floor(nt) or ceil(nt), so just evaluate these two and choose.

Answer (score 1):

Second question: it looks like somewhere you have "x ** y" where y is a float, but x is a NoneType. That probably means nre, npr, vsb, or vsw is a NoneType by the time it is passed into nnuf(). Try printing these variables and see.

Comment: Thanks.  I found the problem (with nref).

Answer (score 1):

`scikits.openopt.MILP` might be what you are looking for. This way you treat the problem as a integer programming problem from the start, with no need for `ceil` or `floor.`